# Unable bind Array values retrived from Excel import in angular

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, express, xlsx

I am trying excel import functionality using xlsx.
I got the array from the below code

```
onFileChange(evt:any){
    const target : DataTransfer = <DataTransfer> (evt.target);
    if(target.files.length !==1) throw new Error('not allowed to upload multiple files');
    const Reader : FileReader = new FileReader(); 
    Reader.onload = (e:any)  => {
      const fileData : string=e.target.result;
      const wb : XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(fileData,{type:'binary'});
      const wsname : string = wb.SheetNames[0];
      const ws : XLSX.WorkSheet = wb.Sheets[wsname];
      this.data =(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws,{header:1}));
      console.log(this.data)
      let x = this.data.slice(1);
      console.log(x)
    };
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.data.length > 0) {
         this.UploadedFileView(this.data);
      }
   }, 500);
    Reader.readAsBinaryString(target.files[0]);
  }

html as below

<input type="file" (change)="onFileChange($event)" multiple="false">

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let row of data">
                <td *ngFor="let cell of row">
                        {{cell}}
                </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

unable to create JSON to save in MongoDB...
if any complete example really helpful

Comment: Why is the `this.UploadedFileView(this.data)` call outside the `onload` handler with a timeout? It should be inside the `onload` handler without the timeout. And please show the output of `console.log(this.data)` (preferably a screenshot) and the expected format. There is not much to go ahead with the info you've provided.

Comment: i want to pass this data to a mat dialog so only `this.UploadedFileView(this.data)` outside the `onload`  function

Comment: `console.log(this.data)` is as follow `Array(6)
0: {Sno: 1, Name: "A", FatherName: "F"}
1: {Sno: 2, Name: "B", FatherName: "G"}
2: {Sno: 3, Name: "C", FatherName: "H"}
3: {Sno: 4, Name: "D", FatherName: "I"}
4: {Sno: 5, Name: "E", FatherName: "J"}
5: "..."
length: 6
__proto__: Array(0)`

Comment: i have solved by myself